# Redirect users who already accepted terms to another webpage (cookies or localStorage)

Tags: javascript, cookies, local-storage

I ve made a mobile version of a website. Before the user see a specific page he must press a button - CONFIRM, which basically confirms that he accepts the terms of our website. Moreover, as soon as the user press the CONFIRM button he is being redirected to the specific page.

My question is how is it possible to use cookies or localStorage in order to redirect the users who already had been accepted the terms to the specific web page?

I am not quite programming savvy so please be nice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check like this:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('accepted') === '1') {
   //redirect - already accepted;
}

// after clicking accept

if (accepted === true) {
    localStorage.setItem('accepted', '1');
    //redirect
}
```

Note that the check and set must be in the same origin.

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/wk9bS/

Of course, you'll need to check that `localStorage` is available (implicit IMO) and provide a fallback mechanism such as persistent cookies:

```
if (!!window.localStorage) {
    //use code above

} else {
    //use fallback

}
```

Comment: Should he add try/catch or if (localStorage){ } around all this code in case the visitor has an old browser?

Comment: @Paul Sure, or better: check that `!!window.localStorage` exist. But that was assumed done already at this stage.